# Connecting AWS RDS from sqlalchemy via EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to AWS RDS (postgres) from EC2 machine with the following code. This works perfectly when I run it from my local machine and creates the table in the database. But when I run it from EC2 it throws an error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out
>           Is the server running on host "" (IP) and accepting
>           TCP/IP connections on port ?

```
import csv
import boto3

from io import StringIO
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, BigInteger, Date,  Integer, String
engine = create_engine('postgresql://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db>')

table_name = 'checking'
meta = MetaData()

table_name = Table(
   table_name, meta,
   Column('phone', BigInteger, primary_key = True),
   Column('first_name', String),
   schema = 'testing'
)

meta.create_all(engine)
```

I believe there is some permission issue with RDS or EC2. On EC2 i have anywhere access to HTTP, HTTPS, TCP, SSH.

Answer (score -1):

Ohh, my postgres access to the  above was not open.

Comment: Could you detail your solution please?