# SSH connection timed out via port forwarding, but not via direct access

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sqlalchemy

I am trying to port forward on an `EC2` instance that has access rights on an RDS instance.

- This grants me access to the VM that has the correct rights on the RDS instance. via ssh:

```bash
<my_user>@<my_local_machine>:~$ ssh ubuntu@ec2-<my_ip>.<my_region>.compute.amazonaws.com

# Connection successful,
ubuntu@ip-<my_ec2_private_ip>:~$ telnet <my_rds_database_endpoint>.<my_region>.rds.amazonaws.com 5432
Trying 10.0.30.11...
Connected to <my_rds_database_endpoint>.<my_region>.rds.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

- Accessing the database is also OK from the VM I previously accessed:

```bash
psql -U <my_user> -h <my_rds_database_endpoint>.<my_region>.rds.amazonaws.com -d <my_database>
```

- Performing portforwarding this way does not seem to work

```bash
ssh -N ubuntu@ec2-<my_ip>.<my_region>.compute.amazonaws.com -L 5432:<my_rds_database_endpoint>.<my_region>.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

-> This successfully runs, but on my (dagster) process that attempts to connect to this instance, I get :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "<my_rds_database_endpoint>.<my_region>.rds.amazonaws.com:5432" (<my_rds_ip>), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

Here is a digest of testing the connectivity of my components:
[image: graphic represenatation of problem]

Via `nmap` from my `localhost`:

```bash
nmap ec2-<my_ip>.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com -PN -p 5432
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-01-10 10:33 CET
Nmap scan report for ec2-<my_ip>.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com (<my_ip>)
Host is up.

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5432/tcp filtered postgresql
```

```bash
nmap <my_rds_database_endpoint>.<my_region>.rds.amazonaws.com -PN -p 5432
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-01-10 10:33 CET
Nmap scan report for <my_rds_database_endpoint>.<my_region>.rds.amazonaws.com (<my_rds_ip>)
Host is up.

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5432/tcp filtered postgresql
```

```bash
nmap localhost -PN -p 5432
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-01-10 10:34 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000070s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851567/connecting-aws-rds-from-sqlalchemy-via-ec2) with the same issue, but unfortunately no detailed solution.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure your forwarding command looks correct to me. I would have expected to command to be: `ssh -N -L 5432:<rds-hostname>:5432 ubuntu@ec2-<my_ip>.<my_region>.compute.amazonaws.com` with the `-N` argument being optional, depending on the behavior you want. Not sure if what you have is equivalent or not. -- you also need to make sure your dagster process is configured to use **localhost port 5432** in its database connection URI. Also check the logs in your ssh tunnel to see other possible issues.

Comment: Is `<my_vm_host_towards_the_rds_instance>` the same as `<my_rds_database_endpoint>.<my_region>.rds.amazonaws.com` ?

Comment: @AnonCoward yes, I correct it in the question

Comment: @sytech, I tried your syntax but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having created a tunnel, you then have to use it.  According to the error message, you are still trying to connect to the rds instance directly.  You need to point your database client at your end of the tunnel, with something like `psql -h localhost -U <my_user> -d <my_database>`.  The tunneling software then makes that pop out the other end and connect to the desired endpoint.

Comment: You are right, I was somehow trying to connect directly to my RDS instance, I needed to change the url to that of `localhost`. I thought port forwarding would have mapped the call to `<my_rds_database_endpoint>.<my_region>.rds.amazonaws.com:5432` to my `localhost:5432`, but if I understand well, I need to do the opposite by attempting to access `localhost:5432` so that it forwards to the rds instance...?